# Workflow Formula to Parse Comments Section on Task Object

Tags: workflow, formula, tasks

I am trying to create a workflow formula that parses the Comments section on a Task. Comments on the Task object will always have 'Dialed: (999)925 - 1234'.  I want to extract (999)999 - 1234 and have that map to another custom field I have on the task object.

So far I have: `IF(Comments(Contains('Dialed'(`

not sure if this is the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far what you have done appears right, let's reiterate what needs to be done and it should give you an idea to get the desired results:

1. Create a Workflow rule on **Task**
2. Supply a filter criteria `IF(Comments(Contains('Dialed:')))`
3. Add **Field update** workflow action
4. Select your **Custom_Field__c** to be updated
5. In the **Specify New Field Value** section, select "Use a formula to set the new value"
6. Enter the formula `Right( Description , Len(Description ) - 7)`

*Note that the length of Filter-Criteria in step-2 was 7, that's why we eliminated those characters from the length of comments to get our desired result*.